# How to find the nth non-blank row of a column?

Tags: excel, vba

OK... Long story short I found a bug in my code where I thought I could simply find the last row in column "A" (which is row 213). However, I actually needed row 219. This gap may be inconsistent, however there are 17 non-blank cells in column "A" (with the 17th non-blank cell being row 213) and the 17th non-blank cell in column "B" is row 219 (that's the row number I need to extract). So I found this formula:

```
TagCount = sheet(1).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

This returns 17...

Now I need to be able to find the 17th (or whatever TagCount is) non-blank cell in column "B" (Actually I just need the row number).

Comment: I'm excited to see a creative answer that doesn't use a loop (not that I can guarantee one exists)

Comment: Yes me too... I could probably stumble around for a bit and try to figure out how to do it with a loop but... I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: Does the last row (219) have a value in it and you're trying to find the nth blank cell in a range of values or are you trying to find the nth blank cell after the populated range?

Comment: Column A is mostly empty with 17 non-blank cells... For example, non-blank cells are: A29, A38, A42... ...A213, etc... where A213 is the 17th non-blank cell. Column B is mostly blank cells with 80 non-blank cells... For example, non-blank cells are: B35, B43, B45... ...B219, etc.... where B219 is the 17th non-blank cell. I want to find this 17th non-blank cell in column B (that is cell B219). Really, what I want is the row number --> "219"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give in and actually use a loop! This will select the nth filled cell in column B where n is the count of tags in column A. This does assume that column B's format is much like column A, so let me know if this needs to be tweaked to work.

```
Sub GetMatchingTagInB()

    Dim TagCount As Long
    TagCount = Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count

    Dim rngB As Range
    Set rngB = Sheets(1).Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rngB
        TagCount = TagCount - 1
        If TagCount = 0 Then
            'do stuff here
            cel.Select
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you... this isn't as simple as I had hoped but probably as simple as it can be.

Comment: @XCELLGUY I'm still holding out hope that this can be accomplished without a loop :)

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I just checked and you don't have to loop through areas, `For Each cel in rngB.Cells` is enough

Answer (score 1):

A possible other way of doing it (if I've understood correctly) would be to use the following. I'm evaluating an Excel formula that would find the nth cell in Column `B` where the nth cell is the count of the number of constants in Column `A`. This is an array formula which could be evaluated in the sheet but evaluating it in VBA as it is a VBA question.

```
Dim BRng As Range, nthCell As Range
Dim EvalStr As String

With Sheets(1)
    Set BRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2))
End With

EvalStr = "=INDEX(" & BRng.Address & ",SMALL(ROW(" & BRng.Address & ")+(100*(" & BRng.Address & "="""")), COUNTA(A:A)))"
Set nthCell = Application.Evaluate(EvalStr)

MsgBox nthCell.Address
```